# What is the difference between curly braces and angle brackets for type hinting in PHP docblock?

Tags: php, docblocks

I see both angle brackets and curly braces used in PHP docblocks used when typehinting arrays.

```php
/**
 * @return array<name:int,link:string,items:array<class:string,active:bool>>
 */
```

Or

```php
/**
 *@return array{name:string,active:bool}
 */
```

I've tried to find something on this type of type hinting in docblocks in the [documentation](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays), but found nothing.

Can anyone clear this up for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some consulting with a colleague, he explained it roughly as follows:

When you are type hinting an array in a php docblock you use the angle brackets `<>` to indicate types at different indices in the array.

You use curly braces `{}` for associative arrays where you specify the keys and types their values have.

```php
/**
 * Only angle brackets:
 * @return array<int,string,bool>
 */
```

Vs.

```php
/**
 * A combination of curly braces and angle brackets
 * @return array{name:string,active:bool,items:array<int,string,bool>}
 */
```

For anyone who had the same question